# Click to open any stack, even if I have no profile

Tags: feature-request, android-app-feed

In the Android app feed, there is a confusing difference in behavior between questions in stacks where I have an active profile and ones I don't. Clicking on the site icon of sites with profile (green freehand circles) will open the list of questions, while ones where I don't (red) won't.

[image]

Is there a reason for this difference? Us there a reason not to support click-to-open for all sites? I know that occasionally, when I see an interesting question on a stack I don't follow, I like to go in and read more. Right now, it involves pulling the sidebar, clicking All Sites and searching for the stack in the whole list, instead of just clicking it.